# Implementation of hashing algorithm with arrays and c++ strings - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, hashtable

I'm getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error, when my hash-function gives similar hash-values. Both "hash" and "Hash" functions should stay the way they are. "keyValue" was also part of the assignment, not the exact implementation, but all Numbers should be upper case (hence "toUpper" function) and start at 1 (for example A=1, B=2 etc.). I guess that "hashInsert" is the one making problems, unfortunately I couldn't figure it out on my own. (and I should use arrays)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**********************/
int toUpper( int );
int keyValue( int );
int hash( int );
int Hash( int );
int hashValue( string, int );
void hashInsert( string[], string );
/**********************/

const int days = 7;
string week[days];

int keyValue( int ch ){
    return toUpper(ch) - 64;
}
int toUpper( int ch ){
    if( ch >= 92 && ch <= 122 )
        return ch - 32;
    return ch;
}
int hash( int ch ){
    return keyValue( ch ) % days;
}
int Hash( int ch ){
    return 1 + (keyValue(ch) % (days-2));
}
int hashValue( string key, int i ){
    return (hash(key[i]) + i*Hash(key[i]) % days);
}
void hashInsert( string table[], string key ){
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < key.length(); i++){
        pos = hashValue( key, i );
        if( (table[pos]).empty() ){
            table[pos] = key;
            break;
        }
    }
}

/*=================== MAIN ===================*/
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){

    hashInsert( week, "Monday" );
//  hashInsert( week, "Tuesday" );
//  hashInsert( week, "Wednesday" );
    hashInsert( week, "Thursday" );
//  hashInsert( week, "Friday" );
    hashInsert( week, "Saturday" );
    hashInsert( week, "Sunday" );

    cout << "0: " << week[0] << endl;   
    cout << "1: " << week[1] << endl;
    cout << "2: " << week[2] << endl;
    cout << "3: " << week[3] << endl;
    cout << "4: " << week[4] << endl;
    cout << "5: " << week[5] << endl;
    cout << "6: " << week[6] << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash(key[i]) + i*Hash(key[i]) % days` should be `(hash(key[i]) + i*Hash(key[i])) % days`.

You're accessing elements of `week` way further than the `week[6]`.